# Select the first radio button knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Consider the following:

```
self.container = ko.observableArray([{name: 'hello', amount: [{item: name, key: '4', selected: 0}, {item: 'name', key: 2, selected: '1'}]}, {name: 'hello', amount: [{item: name, key: 10, selected: 0}, {item: name, key: 8, selected: '1'}]}]);
self.amountSelected = ko.observableArray();
```

If I do:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: container">
  <div data-bind="foreach: amount">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-selection-name" data-bind="attr: {value: key}, checked: $root.amountSelected()[$index()] || selected" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This works, what doesn't work is notice how one of the amounts it's selected as it has a `'1'`

**How do I say, select the currently selected item or use the selected item for this object?**

Is there a way to set, for that index, the radio to selected if the selected attribute on the object is a '1'?

Comment: why you want to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here; and you've got your radio buttons wired up in a very odd way.  Perhaps take another look at the KO [documentation for radio buttons](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html#example-adding-radio-buttons)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select more then one radio, so the `checked` binding dont need to be an `observableArray`  for radios. The best way to set the value of the input  is the `checkedValue` binding, in the snippet there are an example of both, but plese see the documentation [Checked binding KO](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) it is very useful.

```js
function ViewModel(){
  this.container = ko.observableArray([{name: 'hello', amount: [{item: name, key: 4, selected: 0}, {item: 'name', key: 2, selected: '1'}]}, {name: 'hello', amount: [{item: name, key: 10, selected: 0}, {item: name, key: 8, selected: '1'}]}]);
   
   this.amountSelectedRadio = ko.observable(2);
   this.amountSelectedChecked = ko.observableArray([8,4]);  
  
}


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h2>Checked Binding: Radio</h2>
<div data-bind="foreach: container">
  <div data-bind="foreach: amount">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-selection-name" data-bind="checked: $root.amountSelectedRadio, checkedValue: key" />
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Checked Binding: CheckBox</h2>

<div data-bind="foreach: container">
  <div data-bind="foreach: amount">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-selection-name" data-bind="checked: $root.amountSelectedChecked, checkedValue: key" />
  </div>
</div>
```